# How to use an AND LIKE parameter in an SSRS report with an additional OR option?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-like

I have a Dataset Query in SSRS as follows

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE Account_Code LIKE @Department+'%'
```

This is so that the SSRS report is able to provide a drop-down of specified available departments based on the first letter of the Account Code(s) in the Account_Code table.

I have set the `@Department` parameter in SSRS Report Builder with specified available values as shown below...

[image]

However, I need Department 3 to be based on **two** criteria (i.e. with an Account_Code beginning with 'C' **or** 'D'). Entering the expression 'C OR D' in parameter properties does not work. Do I need to re-think the dataset query itself or can this be done in SSRS parameters with just my LIKE `@Department` clause?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the third value to `[c-d]`. See the example below.

```
DECLARE @Department varchar(10)
SET @Department = '[c-D]'

CREATE TABLE #Test (Account_Code char(2))

INSERT INTO #Test(Account_Code) VALUES
('CA'),
('CB'),
('DA'),
('DB'),
('AZ'),
('AY'),
('BZ'),
('BY')

SELECT * 
FROM #Test
WHERE Account_Code LIKE @Department + '%'

DROP TABLE #Test
```